# How do questions per day get calculated?

Tags: discussion, questions

On the Area51 stats, it says we have a rate of 8.8 questions per day. And the rate is dropping very quickly (was at above 10 some days ago).

I tried to redo the maths: we have 585 questions and the site is 33 days in beta. Simple math does not apply:

```
585 / 33 = 17.7
```

Where does the gap between 8.8 and 17.7 questions per day come from?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As in many other places, hovering over the number explains how it's obtained:

> questions per day on average over the past two weeks

Not clear if today is included (is this based on UTC day, or 24*7 hours?) but in any case, the number is about what I get by counting [the questions asked in the last 14 days](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/search?q=created%3A13d..+is%3Aq) (including today) and dividing by 14.

It is expected that the rate of new questions will drop after the private beta, followed by slow growth over many months (and years) as  new participants join the site one by one. See [What is the typical growth pattern of a new beta site in the first few weeks?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/227007)